# how to disable the entire dropdown control in html

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

i see there is a disabled property on a specific item in the dropdown list but is there an enabled property on the whole html dropdown itself?

any suggestions?

Comment: disabled="disabled" should work on the select element too

Comment: Why wouldn't you just *try* something like this?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `<select>` element. That it is rendered as a drop-down list (for single-selection) is a User Agent thing, HTML doesn't specify this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [the HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) a `select` element has a `disabled` attribute.

So

```
<select disabled>
  <option>Something</option>
</select>
```

should work

Answer (score 15):

```
disabled="disabled"
```

This will disable a value within the combo box (it will still show up, but it will not have the ability to be selected):

```
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This will disable the whole combo box:

```
<select disabled="disabled">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

may [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/Disableandenableadropdownlistcombobox.htm) will help

is same as :

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          function makeDisable(){
          var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
          x.disabled=true
          }
         function makeEnable(){
             var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
              x.disabled=false
         }</script></head><body><form>
        <select id="mySelect"><option>Apple</option><option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" onclick="makeDisable()" value="Disable list">
        <input type="button" onclick="makeEnable()" value="Enable list">
        </form>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: how would i do this with buttons.  i want this to be disable from the initial page load