# Disable DropDown in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to disable an HTML DropDown in Rails, and I found this solution:
[how to disable the entire dropdown control in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227212/how-to-disable-the-entire-dropdown-control-in-html)

So, I have this:

```
f.select( ...., :disabled => true)
```

But, the problem is, when the DropDown is disabled, it does not show in the `params` collection.

EDIT:
This is my situation:
I have a form with a `text_field` and a `select` field. There are two cases:

- The user creates a new item directly. If so, she will choose a category from the select field.
- The user creates a new item, after redirecting from a category page. In this case, the select field is set to the value of the category, and should be disabled.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting to show in the params collection? Do you want a default value?

Comment: Disabled form elements won't submit their value with a form submission.  Take a look at this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment in the original question, disabled form element values won't be present in the params on a form submission.  To get around this, try using a hidden field to hold and submit the value you want.

Assuming some variables and whatnot are setup to help decide whether the select field should be disabled:

```
# ...
f.select(..., :disabled => @category_already_chosen)
f.hidden_field(...) if @category_already_chosen
# ...
```

Obviously this can be changed to suit your needs, but the basic idea is there.  If you've already chosen a category and want the select field to be disabled, make a hidden field.  If you haven't chosen a category, omit the hidden field and allow users to make use of the select field.

As shown in the [link I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value), this is probably the simplest way to get around this limitation, without resorting to using Javascript to play with parameters after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I would add query string parameters to your redirect_to call

```
redirect_to :action => form_path, :category => :whatever_category_they_came_from, :disabled => true
```

Then in your form

```
:selected => params[:category], :disabled => params[:disabled]
```